# when I back to app, why getActivity returns null?

Tags: android

I developed a simple android app.

Activity:

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

ArrayList<Fragment> fgs = new ArrayList<>();

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {

    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    fgs.add(new MyFragment1());
    fgs.add(new MyFragment2());

    ViewPager viewPager = (ViewPager) findViewById(R.id.container);
    viewPager.setAdapter(new FragmentPagerAdapter(getSupportFragmentManager()) {
        @Override
        public Fragment getItem(int position) {
            switch (position) {
                case 0:
                    return fgs.get(position);
                case 1:
                    return fgs.get(position);
                default:
                    return null;
            }
        }

        @Override
        public int getCount() {
            return fgs.size();
        }
    });
    viewPager.addOnPageChangeListener(new ViewPager.OnPageChangeListener() {
        @Override
        public void onPageScrolled(int position, float positionOffset, int positionOffsetPixels) {
        }
        @Override
        public void onPageSelected(int position) {
            switch (position) {
                case 0:
                    ((MyFragment1) fgs.get(0)).display();
                    return;
            }
        }
        @Override
        public void onPageScrollStateChanged(int state) {}
    });
}

}
```

Fragment1

```
public class MyFragment1 extends Fragment {

String mString;

@Nullable
@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, @Nullable ViewGroup container, @Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {

    View v = inflater.inflate(R.layout.my_fragment, container, false);

    mString = "MyFragment1";
    ((TextView)v.findViewById(R.id.text)).setText(mString);
    return v;
}

public void display()
{
    Toast.makeText(getActivity(), mString, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

}
}
```

Fragment2

```
public class MyFragment2 extends Fragment {

String mString;

@Nullable
@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, @Nullable ViewGroup container, @Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {

    View v = inflater.inflate(R.layout.my_fragment, container, false);
    mString = "MyFragment2";

    ((TextView)v.findViewById(R.id.text)).setText(mString);
    return v;
}

}
```

I tested this app behavir under the situation that memory of it is released by OS.(I made "Don't keep activities" checked.) 
Under this sitiaion, when I close this app and back to app and scroll to Fragment1, NullPointerException happened.
I thought that when I back to the app, all work OK. Because when I back to the app, the app start over again.
Why does this happen? How I solve this problem?

ErrorLog:

```
 Exception in MessageQueue callback: handleReceiveCallback java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'android.content.res.Resources android.content.Context.getResources()' on a null object reference
                                                                               at android.widget.Toast.<init>(Toast.java:102)
                                                                               at android.widget.Toast.makeText(Toast.java:260)
                                                                               at knkj28.com.experiment.MyFragment1.display(MyFragment1.java:33)
                                                                               at knkj28.com.experiment.MainActivity$2.onPageSelected(MainActivity.java:52)
                                                                               at android.support.v4.view.ViewPager.dispatchOnPageSelected(ViewPager.java:1967)
                                                                               at android.support.v4.view.ViewPager.scrollToItem(ViewPager.java:685)
                                                                               at android.support.v4.view.ViewPager.setCurrentItemInternal(ViewPager.java:669)
                                                                               at android.support.v4.view.ViewPager.onTouchEvent(ViewPager.java:2284)
                                                                               at android.view.View.dispatchTouchEvent(View.java:9991)
                                                                               at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTransformedTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:2663)
                                                                               at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:2344)
                                                                               at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTransformedTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:2669)
                                                                               at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:2358)
                                                                               at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTransformedTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:2669)
                                                                               at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:2358)
                                                                               at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTransformedTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:2669)
                                                                               at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:2358)
                                                                               at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTransformedTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:2669)
                                                                               at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:2358)
                                                                               at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTransformedTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:2669)
                                                                               at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:2358)
                                                                               at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTransformedTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:2669)
                                                                               at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:2358)
                                                                               at com.android.internal.policy.DecorView.superDispatchTouchEvent(DecorView.java:413)
                                                                               at com.android.internal.policy.PhoneWindow.superDispatchTouchEvent(PhoneWindow.java:1810)
                                                                               at android.app.Activity.dispatchTouchEvent(Activity.java:3102)
                                                                               at android.support.v7.view.WindowCallbackWrapper.dispatchTouchEvent(WindowCallbackWrapper.java:71)
                                                                               at com.android.internal.policy.DecorView.dispatchTouchEvent(DecorView.java:375)
                                                                               at android.view.View.dispatchPointerEvent(View.java:10211)
                                                                               at android.view.ViewRootImpl$ViewPostImeInputStage.processPointerEvent(ViewRootImpl.java:4444)
                                                                               at android.view.ViewRootImpl$ViewPostImeInputStage.onProcess(ViewRootImpl.java:4312)
                                                                               at android.view.ViewRootImpl$InputStage.deliver(ViewRootImpl.java:3859)
                                                                               at android.view.ViewRootImpl$InputStage.onDeliverToNext(ViewRootImpl.java:3912)
                                                                               at android.view.ViewRootImpl$InputStage.forward(ViewRootImpl.java:3878)
                                                                               at android.view.ViewRootImpl$AsyncInputStage.forward(ViewRootImpl.java:4005)
                                                                               at android.view.ViewRootImpl$InputStage.apply(ViewRootImpl.java:3886)
                                                                               at android.view.ViewRootImpl$AsyncInputStage.apply(ViewRootImpl.java:4062)
                                                                               at android.view.ViewRootImpl$InputStage.deliver(ViewRootImpl.java:3859)
                                                                               at android.view.ViewRootImpl$InputStage.onDeliverToNext(ViewRootImpl.java:3912)
                                                                               at android.view.ViewRootImpl$InputStage.forward(ViewRootImpl.java:3878)
                                                                               at android.view.ViewRootImpl$InputStage.apply(ViewRootImpl.java:3886)
                                                                               at android.view.ViewRootImpl$InputStage.deliver(ViewRootImpl.java:3859)
                                                                               at android.view.ViewRootImpl.deliverInputEvent(ViewRootImpl.java:6220)
                                                                               at android.view.ViewRootImpl.doProcessInputEvents(ViewRootImpl.java:6194)
                                                                               at android.view.ViewRootImpl.enqueueInputEvent(ViewRootImpl.java:6155)
                                                                               at android.view.ViewRootImpl$WindowInputEventReceiver.onInputEvent(ViewRootImpl.java:6323)
                                                                               at android.view.InputEventReceiver.dispatchInputEvent(InputEventReceiver.java:185)
                                                                               at android.os.MessageQueue.nativePollOnce(Native Method)
                                                                               at android.os.MessageQueue.next(MessageQueue.java:331)
                                                                               at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:219)
                                                                               at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6217)
                                                                               at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
                                                                               at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:865)
                                                                            at com.android.internal.os.
Shutting down VM


                                                                         --------- beginning of crash
 FATAL EXCEPTION: main
                                                                         Process: knkj28.com.experiment, PID: 6025
                                                                         java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'android.content.res.Resources android.content.Context.getResources()' on a null object reference
                                                                             at android.widget.Toast.<init>(Toast.java:102)
                                                                             at android.widget.Toast.makeText(Toast.java:260)
                                                                             at knkj28.com.experiment.MyFragment1.display(MyFragment1.java:33)
                                                                             at knkj28.com.experiment.MainActivity$2.onPageSelected(MainActivity.java:52)
                                                                             at android.support.v4.view.ViewPager.dispatchOnPageSelected(ViewPager.java:1967)
                                                                             at android.support.v4.view.ViewPager.scrollToItem(ViewPager.java:685)
                                                                             at android.support.v4.view.ViewPager.setCurrentItemInternal(ViewPager.java:669)
                                                                             at android.support.v4.view.ViewPager.onTouchEvent(ViewPager.java:2284)
                                                                             at android.view.View.dispatchTouchEvent(View.java:9991)
                                                                             at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTransformedTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:2663)
                                                                             at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:2344)
                                                                             at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTransformedTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:2669)
                                                                             at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:2358)
                                                                             at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTransformedTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:2669)
                                                                             at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:2358)
                                                                             at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTransformedTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:2669)
                                                                             at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:2358)
                                                                             at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTransformedTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:2669)
                                                                             at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:2358)
                                                                             at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTransformedTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:2669)
                                                                             at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:2358)
                                                                             at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTransformedTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:2669)
                                                                             at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:2358)
                                                                             at com.android.internal.policy.DecorView.superDispatchTouchEvent(DecorView.java:413)
                                                                             at com.android.internal.policy.PhoneWindow.superDispatchTouchEvent(PhoneWindow.java:1810)
                                                                             at android.app.Activity.dispatchTouchEvent(Activity.java:3102)
                                                                             at android.support.v7.view.WindowCallbackWrapper.dispatchTouchEvent(WindowCallbackWrapper.java:71)
                                                                             at com.android.internal.policy.DecorView.dispatchTouchEvent(DecorView.java:375)
                                                                             at android.view.View.dispatchPointerEvent(View.java:10211)
                                                                             at android.view.ViewRootImpl$ViewPostImeInputStage.processPointerEvent(ViewRootImpl.java:4444)
                                                                             at android.view.ViewRootImpl$ViewPostImeInputStage.onProcess(ViewRootImpl.java:4312)
                                                                             at android.view.ViewRootImpl$InputStage.deliver(ViewRootImpl.java:3859)
                                                                             at android.view.ViewRootImpl$InputStage.onDeliverToNext(ViewRootImpl.java:3912)
                                                                             at android.view.ViewRootImpl$InputStage.forward(ViewRootImpl.java:3878)
                                                                             at android.view.ViewRootImpl$AsyncInputStage.forward(ViewRootImpl.java:4005)
                                                                             at android.view.ViewRootImpl$InputStage.apply(ViewRootImpl.java:3886)
                                                                             at android.view.ViewRootImpl$AsyncInputStage.apply(ViewRootImpl.java:4062)
                                                                             at android.view.ViewRootImpl$InputStage.deliver(ViewRootImpl.java:3859)
                                                                             at android.view.ViewRootImpl$InputStage.onDeliverToNext(ViewRootImpl.java:3912)
                                                                             at android.view.ViewRootImpl$InputStage.forward(ViewRootImpl.java:3878)
                                                                             at android.view.ViewRootImpl$InputStage.apply(ViewRootImpl.java:3886)
                                                                             at android.view.ViewRootImpl$InputStage.deliver(ViewRootImpl.java:3859)
                                                                             at android.view.ViewRootImpl.deliverInputEvent(ViewRootImpl.java:6220)
                                                                             at android.view.ViewRootImpl.doProcessInputEvents(ViewRootImpl.java:6194)
                                                                             at android.view.ViewRootImpl.enqueueInputEvent(ViewRootImpl.java:6155)
                                                                             at android.view.ViewRootImpl$WindowInputEventReceiver.onInputEvent(ViewRootImpl.java:6323)
                                                                             at android.view.InputEventReceiver.dispatchInputEvent(InputEventReceiver.java:185)
                                                                             at android.os.MessageQueue.nativePollOnce(Native Method)
                                                                             at android.os.MessageQueue.next(MessageQueue.java:331)
                                                                             at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:219)
                                                                             at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6217)
                                                                             at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
    08-16 13:32:16.701 6025-6025/knkj28.com.experiment E/AndroidRuntime:     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:865)
                                                                             at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:755)
```

Answer (score 0):

```
public void display() {
     if (mString.isEmpty()) {
         mString = getActivity().getClass().getSimpleName();
     }
    Toast.makeText(getActivity(), mString, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
}
```

Answer (score -1):

Do you know how to read code, right? The first 3 lines of your stack trace are telling you that Context.getResources() is applied on a null reference, when your code call Toast.makeText() which initialize the Toast class. Look at the source:

```
    public Toast(Context context) {
    mContext = context;
    mTN = new TN();
    mTN.mY = context.getResources().getDimensionPixelSize(
            com.android.internal.R.dimen.toast_y_offset);
```

so it means you're passing a null context to it. On your side you call:

```
Toast.makeText(getActivity()
```

which means the getActivity() is null, which is not a big surprise to me given you're asking the system to enforce to kill all the activities. So, you should have your code ready for the host activity to be null.

Also, if you read at the docs:

```
    /**
     * Return the {@link FragmentActivity} this fragment is currently associated with.
     * May return {@code null} if the fragment is associated with a {@link Context}
     * instead.
     */
```

it means you're not binding the fragment to the host activity. Make sure you read how to [properly attach the fragment to the activity](https://developer.android.com/guide/components/fragments.html), also [here](https://developer.android.com/training/basics/fragments/fragment-ui.html).

Comment: I got it. But why does my code could not associate fragment with activity? It 
 work properly the first time. Even if OS enforce the app, It should work properly because both activity and fragment are created again and life cycles start again like the first time. Do I misunderstand somethig?

Comment: That depends on how you bind the fragment to the activity. Look at where does that happens in your code (possibly show it to us). Also, debug getActivity() and see the returned null there. Make the code robust and ready for it, because even if this time you're doing something wrong, generally speaking within a Fragment you've no guarantee that your host activity will not be killed (by the system) at any time, and still some fragment's code (say a callback) could execute delayed.